# ps3 controller problems

Tags: ps3

I've gone thru a cpl walkthrus on how to get my ps3 controller working on ubuntu. i have a eee pc 1005hab and i get this far:

Type the following command to install the necessary USB library:
sudo apt-get install libusb-dev libusb-0.1-4

Connect the PS3 controller, then download the "sixpair" driver to your downloads directory

Type the following command to switch to the download directory:

cd /home/user/downloads

Replace "user" with your user name.

This is as far as i get then it says:
bash: cd/ashley/downloads: No such file or directory

Cna anyone help please

(i'm sorry if this is in the wrong place, I would be happy to repost if it is a problem)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a space between `cd` and `/home/ashley/downloads`, but the point is, to change the current directory to the one, where the downloaded file is.

Comment: even when i put the space i get the same problem

Comment: In your post, the `home` part is also missing

Comment: lol i forgot to type that lemme see if it works

Comment: when i type this cd /home/ashley/downloads

Comment: i get this  cd: /home/ashley/downloads: No such file or directory

Comment: Where did you download the driver? Did you select a download location in the browser?

Comment: i fixed it it needed to be a capital D for downloads thanks for the help